# Bash - stdir words to file

Tags: bash, variables, append, stdin

I am trying to store whole user input in a bash variable (appending variable).
Then to sort them etc.
The problem is that for input f.e.:

```
sdsd fff sss
asdasds
```

It creates this output:

```
fff
sdsd
sssasdasds
```

Expected output is:

```
asdasds
fff
sdsd
sss
```

Code follows:

```
content=''
while read line
do
    content+=$(echo "$line")
done
result=`echo "$content" | sed -r 's/[^a-zA-Z ]+/ /g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/\n/g'`
echo "$result" >> "$dictionary"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't providing a space when you are appending.

```
content+=$(echo "$line")
```

You need to make sure there is a space between the end of the old value and the new value.

```
content+=" $line"
```

(There's no need for `echo` for this either as @gniourf_gniourf correctly pointed out.)

Comment: The subshell-`echo` combo looks... funny, but is definitely useless.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Very true. I'm going to chalk that up to my general tendency to leave OP details intact combined with being distracted.

Answer (score 2):

Something that will achieve what you're showing in your example:

```
words_ary=()
while read -r -a line_ary; do
    (( ${#line_ary[@]} )) || continue # skip empty lines
    words_ary+=( "${line_ary[@],,}" ) # The ,, is to convert to lower-case
done
printf '%s\n' "${words_ary[@]}" | sort -u >> "$dictionary"
```

- We're splitting input into words at spaces and put these words in array `line_ary`
- We're checking that we have a non-empty input
- we append each word, converted to lowercase, from input to the array `words_ary`
- finally we sort each word from `words_ary` and append the sorted words to file `$dictionary`.